# Why would a script have multiple questions marks in the OptionString of getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a script that has the following line:

`while getopts "b:?1:?2:?g:r:n:t:?o:?" opt; do`

how is this any different than:

`while getopts "b:1:2:g:r:n:t:o:" opt; do`

Comment: On what operating system and in what shell is that script? What research did you do? And you tagged `getopt` not `getopts` - they differ, a lot. The `?` in `getopts` used as a option character is just invalid. Is the script available on the internet? Did you ask the author of the script what he meant? I _guess_ the author meant that the option argument is optional, I wonder if such implementation exists. Is there a custom `getopts` implementation in the script?

Comment: sorry it is `getopts` with an `s`.  Ubuntu and bash but I found it in a CWL script.  I can try to change the tag.  I read a lot of different pages such as https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/getopts.htm and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/g_commands/getopts.html but they only refer to `?` as being special character set to $opt.  Script is here https://github.com/litd/analysis-workflows/blob/master/definitions/tools/sequence_align_and_tag.cwl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is this any different than:

The first one is invalid. It's as different, as `?` will be most probably ignored by most `getopts` implementations, but if `getopts` decided to error on invalid `optstring` that would be fine. From [posix getopts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html):

> optstring
>
> A string containing the option characters recognized by the utility invoking getopts. [...]
>
> The characters <question-mark> and <colon> shall not be used as option characters by an application. [...]

There are no other mentions of `?`, except for error handling. `getopt` is a really simple utility, the `?` is returned by `getopt` in case of parsing error.

The author most probably meant to do "optional option argument" - `getopt` does not support such functionality (and if it would, I believe it would be denoted by two `::` like in GNU `getopt`).

Looking at [bash sources getopt.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/getopt.c#L182), `bash` uses simple `strchr` to scan for the option in `optstring`. Because there's `?`, it is interpreted as an option - it becomes impossible (or unnecessary hard) to differentiate between error and success, as `?` is returned in case of error.

```
$ OPTIND=0; set -- -'?' -g; while getopts "something:?does_not_matter" opt; do echo "$opt" "$OPTARG"; done
?                                              # This is valid -? option
bash: option requires an argument -- g
?                                              # This is error

$ OPTIND=0; set -- -'?'; while getopts "something:does_not_matter" opt; do echo "$opt" "$OPTARG"; done
bash: illegal option -- ?
?                                              # This is error
```